# Crash errorcode: CLR20r3

Tags: c#, forms, debugging, installation

I created a software in Visual Studio (C#).

The software works fine, and I created an installer.

After installing my software, I am tryin to open it with clicking on the Shortcut-icon, and I get a popup with a crash-error, code: CLR20r3

Can anyone explain me why this is happening? This didn't happen at the first time installing, but after the second time.

On one of the rules I found this:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

EDIT:

I see that my installation folder is missing my .dll file...

Comment: That's a version number, not an error code.  Use the debugger.

Comment: Oh... You mean the visual studio debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like the installation miss to install a dll.

Review your \bin\release (or \bin\debug) directory where you compile your program and your installation dir to see if something is missing.

Comment: In the bin\debug folder I see one .dll file. Named to my ClassLibrary.

Comment: which dll is? Try to add it to your installation project directly (Is a standar installation project of Visual C# 2012?)

Comment: I re-installed my application. Now my dll isn't missing... I created the installer with Visual Studio 2012